# Is there an Python function for Iteration on code line by line (Syntactic rather than lexical)

Tags: python, parsing

I'm working on a feature that behaves like a debugger,
I am looking for a function that will help me to pass a file by line in syntactic way.

**For Example:**

```
a = 3 + 4 +\
5
```

The function will return one line and not 2 lines -

(And there are other examples that go beyond line by line in the file does not catch the syntactic line)

Comment: Perhaps `ast.parse()` is what you want.

Comment: Yes, that function can help me, but do you know if there is a way to print the ast instance (syntactic line)??

Comment: You should read the `ast` documentation and tutorials.